# select dymanic path & prompt to save file in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am looking dynamic path to be taken for uploading excel file and should ask where to save the file. here is my code.`where as i tried but it is taking only static path. Any help would be appreciated.

'To Combine Sheets

```
Dim WorkbookDestination As Workbook
Dim WorkbookSource As Workbook
Dim WorksheetSource As Worksheet
Dim FolderLocation As String
Dim strFilename As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'This line will need to be modified depending on location of source folder
FolderLocation = "U:\ECA"  'file location need to be dynamic

'Set the current directory to the the folder path.
ChDrive FolderLocation
ChDir FolderLocation

'Dialog box to determine which files to use. Use ctrl+a to select all files in folder.
SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", MultiSelect:=True)

'Create a new workbook
Set WorkbookDestination = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
strFilename = Dir(FolderLocation & "\*.xls", vbNormal) 'file name should be specified by user input and output file

'Iterate for each file in folder
If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until strFilename = ""

        Set WorkbookSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderLocation & "\" & strFilename)
        Set WorksheetSource = WorkbookSource.Worksheets(1)
        WorksheetSource.Copy After:=WorkbookDestination.Worksheets(WorkbookDestination.Worksheets.Count)
        WorkbookSource.Close False
    strFilename = Dir()
Loop
WorkbookDestination.Worksheets(1).Delete

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FolderLocation
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True`
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic path'?

Answer (score 0):

1. This block of code is good once everything is running properly:
    `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`
    `Application.EnableEvents = False`
    `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
   Until your code is completely debugged, though, it will make your life a nightmare. Comment those 3 out until this procedure is running the way you want it.
2. you appear to declare (`Dim`) some of your variables, but not all. I would strongly recommend adding `Option Explicit` to the top of all your code modules to force variable declaration prior to use - it helps prevent typos in variable names from messing things up down the road.
3. You assign `SelectedFiles` the return value from `Application.GetOpenFilename`, but don't ever use it. When it's assigned, you will have an array of file names that the user selected, and they will include the full path. This may provide the path information you need (the dialog box will allow the user to navigate to the desired folder), but I'm not sure, because...
4. You assign `strFilename = Dir(FolderLocation & "\*.xls", vbNormal)` which gives you the first `*.xls` file located in `FolderLocation`. You then loop through all the `*.xls` files there.

I would suggest that using your existing code, you could pull the path information from `SelectedFiles` like this:

```
SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
         filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", MultiSelect:=False)
If InStrRev(SelectedFiles, "\") > 0 Then
  FolderLocation = Left(SelectedFiles, InStrRev(SelectedFiles, "\"))
End If
```

Note that I changed `Multiselect:=False` to allow the user to only select one file - I don't see where you're using this variable anywhere else, so I've modified it to simply use it as a path picker. If that's incorrect, you'll have to make another modification to select the path. Otherwise, `FolderLocation` will now point to the directory that the user selected and you can continue your looping after that using the folder they selected.